# How Google cookies distinguish new device and new browser but old device

Tags: browser, gmail

I want to ask how Google manages to distinguish between new device and new browser used using cookies. 
As for example, when we open Gmail with a new browser (say Firefox) from the same device, we don't get any varification mail from Gmail team. But when we do the same with a new device we get a mail where Gmail team varifies whether we have got a new device. How does Google make sure whether we are using new device/ same device but new browser? I know that cookies are both browser and device dependant. So how is it possible to analyse new device even when new browser also acts as a new user?